# Multi-objective-optimization - minimize two functions in python

Tags: python, optimization, minimize

Problem:
I am facing a mechanical-engineering problem and want to solve it with multicriteria optimization.
I got 10 production plants.
Each got different maintenance costs, lead times and capacities.
I want to select the plants that are able to deal with the order capacity and at the same time are the cheapest (costs) and fastest (lead times).

Attempt:
I want to minimize 2 functions.
Both functions depend on x1 to x10 (each production plant).
The first function describes the cost.
The second function describes the lead times.
Condition is that the sum of the capacity of the choosen plants is > a known value.

x can assume either 0 or 1

Question:
Is there a python library that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: This is so small you could just enumerate all feasible solutions.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted an "automatic" solution so badly that i overlooked how easy it is to get the solution for this case.